# Radio button strange "extra" dot on the side

Tags: html, css

im trying to customize a Google Form, The form it self has 2 radio buttons, but the strange thing is that they have two "dots" on the left side, is it possible to remove them?

/ These dot's down here /
[image]

A snipet of the code looks like this:

```
<ul class="ss-choices" role="radiogroup" style="text-align:center" aria-label="Kan du tänkta dig att hålla en unconference session?  "><li class="ss-choice-item"><label><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block" style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="entry.1554315178" value="Ja, jag g&ouml;r det g&auml;rna" id="group_1554315178_1" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="Ja, jag g&ouml;r det g&auml;rna" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
<span class="ss-choice-label" style="text-align:center">Ja, jag gör det gärna</span>
</label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block" style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="entry.1554315178" value="Nej, inte den h&auml;r g&aring;ngen" id="group_1554315178_2" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="Nej, inte den h&auml;r g&aring;ngen" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
<span class="ss-choice-label">Nej, inte den här gången</span>
</label></li></ul>
```

Comment: those aren't strange extra dots, those are the list item dots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you using list.

`The <ul> tag defines an unordered (bulleted) list.`

Add this to your css:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VAJJ/1/)

Comment: I use bootstrap.css, and in that css i can find this ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul ul,
ol ul,

Comment: You don't go that way. I just posted the general solution. In your example you go like `ul.ss-choices > li{list-style-type: none;}` http://jsfiddle.net/5VAJJ/3/

Comment: Should i replace "ul.ss-choices" with li{list-style-type: none;}? Im trying to search in the bootstrap.css for "ul.ss-choices" but cant find any.

Comment: Just add this in your css file. No need to replace.

Comment: Thank Alek, i tried to add that to the css, should it be placed in some special part in the css or just any were? I added it like this, but the "dots" are still there:
http://imgur.com/Rf5Thcu

Comment: Yes, if you load this css file. If it doesn't work just and `!important`, like that `ul.ss-choices > li{list-style-type: none !important;}`

Comment: Thanks Alek, god damn ima retard haha, but now it works, thank you so much <3